# How can I forward port 8080 from my linux machine to be visible on port 2007 of my internal network using ssh?

Tags: debian, ssh, putty, port

I have a linux server hosting an applcation on **port 8080**

Inside putty, i have create a port forward from port **2007 to 8080** by specifying the public IP of my server, where's covered in red below

[image: putty config]

How ever, my applicaton only works when connecting to **localhost:2007**
and it **does no work** using by calling my **192.168.0.xxx:2007**

I intend, to further expose 2007 from my machine to another port, to make publicily visible from my personal domain

I also want to add, the i have set:

```
AllowTcpFowarding yes
```

inside my sshd_config file.

Thanks in advance. Look forward to your replies

Answer (score 0):

You say that connecting to `localhost:2007` works. This means that the tunnel is working (the Linux part). Your question is a Windows/Putty/networking question.

According to the [Putty manual](https://www.putty.be/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding) the source port (in your case `2007`) is default bound to the localhost IP.

The [manual](https://www.putty.be/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-portfwd) also says that is possible to bind a different IP address:

> In the ‘Source port’ box, you can also optionally enter an IP address to listen on, by specifying (for instance) 127.0.0.5:79.

In your case you should bind it to `192.168.0.xxx:2007`.

Comment: Appreciate that, it does work indeed - it does make sense, however, the UI makes it seem, only a port number fits there, being smaller than the other field... Thanks for documentation above, appreciated.

Comment: Hi @melki0795 if the above answer has helped you and was the solution. Could you please mark it as the accepted answer by using the checkmark to the left of the answer?